# Converting Integer to a String

Tags: java

```
public enum TrafficLight {
    RED(20),
    YELLOW(3),
    GREEN(10);

    int duration;

    TrafficLight(int newDuraction) {
        duration = newDuraction;
    }

    public int getDuraction() {
        return duration;
    }
```

in the test class it's like:

```
public class TrafficLightTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (TrafficLight trafficLight : TrafficLight.values()) {
            System.out.println(trafficLight.name() + ": duraction " + trafficLight.getDuraction());
        }
    }
}
```

and i would like for example: "GREEN: duraction 10 " the number 10 to be like "**********".

10 = "**********" (ten asterisks)

3 = "***"  (three asterisks)

i hope you get the idea. Thanks :)

Comment: What research have you done?  The way it's worded, this sounds like "Enums 101" to me.  Also, can you please clarify what exactly you're expecting to see? It's a little confusing as to whether you want to see the name or the integer value of the enum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a for loop for printing "*" the required number of times

```
System.out.print(trafficLight.name() + ": duraction " ); //change this to Print instead of println
for(int i=0;i<trafficLight.getDuraction();i++)
    System.out.print("*");
System.out.println();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like :-

```
    public class TrafficLightTest { 
        public static String getAsteric(int input){ // return * using the int input
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i =0 ; i< input; i++)
                sb.append("*");
            return sb.toString();
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (TrafficLight trafficLight : TrafficLight.values()) {
               System.out.println(trafficLight.name() + ": duraction " + TrafficLightTest.getAsteric(trafficLight.getDuraction()));   // prints * equal to int input 
        }
    }
}
```